# Move files from the import directory into archive using Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, limit, move, archive

I have a requirement to move all files from the import directory monitored by Camel into another directory.  For that I used the move and moveFailed options of Camel in my route.

I have a MaxFilesAllowedInArchive parameter in a properties files and  if the file limit is exceeded, the oldest file has to be deleted.

How can I make a custom move and moveFailed to control the number of files moved and to keep latest files in archive?

Answer (score 0):

Camel doesn't have a component that operates off of filesystem meta data (such as counts and dates), but you can easily implement this using a customer processor that uses the new Java Paths and Files API's.

Create a timer/quartz route that calls to a customer processor. In this customer processor, list files in your "move" and "moveFailed" directory to count the contents (and sort by date). If the MaxFilesAllowsInArchive is exceeded, then delete X number of files from the folders.